# Class Object not working as expected in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina

I have a class named `startPlatform` in Python. I am using the ursina engine. When I call it, it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/eshan/OneDrive/Desktop/ursina-platformer-maker/main.py", line 29, in <module>`
    StartPlatform(position = (10, 5, 8))
  File "C:/Users/eshan/OneDrive/Desktop/ursina-platformer-maker/main.py", line 17, in __init__
    super().__init__(
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

The argument are correct, and I don't know what's happening. Here's my Code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.sky import Sky
from ursina.shaders import basic_lighting_shader

app = Ursina()
editor = EditorCamera()

def input(key):
    if held_keys["q"]:
        quit()

class StartPlatform():
    def __init__(self, position = (0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            model = "cube",
            position = position,
            scale = (5, 2, 6),
            collider = "mesh",
            shader = basic_lighting_shader,
            texture = "white_cube",
            color = color.lime
        )

Sky()
StartPlatform(position = (10, 5, 8))
app.run()
```

Comment: Please read [formatting help](/help/formatting) for tips on how to format your code. For code fences, type three backticks on the lines before and after your code. Don't format each line as a separate inline code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StartPlatform` does not inherit `Entity`, which I assume is what you want it to be.

```py
class StartPlatform():
```

Should be:

```py
class StartPlatform(Entity):
```

Comment: can I use it for mouse position or Button?

Comment: What is "it" referring to? No, mouse position and Button are not things you can *do*